# Setting vs Initialising properties?

Tags: objective-c, properties

While I understand that properties auto-generate setter and getter methods for you I'm not sure I understand the difference between setting and initialising.

Getters are reading the value of the property when they get called but setters would get called every time you change the value.

However, to initialise a property - how is this different to setting its value? Does initialisation always come first, and then once a property is somehow initialised it can be later set with some (new) value via the setter method?

Hope someone can help clear this up.

Comment: Initialise is mostly a synonym for setting it the first time.  Do you have a specific example that's causing confusion?

Comment: Sadly not, I had been reading up on initializers in relation to creating instances of a class and then realised that initialization also applies to properties and I just could not see how initialising a property is different to setting it, unlike with actual instances you want to create and initialise.

Comment: Instances are different because they are actual objects that need to have internal setup.  With a property, you're usually dealing with a simple value or a pointer, either of which is set/initialized by assignment.  You can't have a property that's an actual Obj-C object, only a pointer to one.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I came across a designated initialiser example again in apple's obj-c book online which is - (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName
                                            dateOfBirth:(NSDate *)aDOB; and realise each property via its setter method will get set via this method. How else might a property be set?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @PhillipMills but would you also know if 'setting' would be used more often in relation to properties than 'initialising'?

Comment: Logically, that's what you'd expect.  Every property initialization is a form of 'set' but most setting is not initialization.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much!